# connect to SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Services) from ubuntu

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, ubuntu, ssas

I have an ASP.NET Core(.net 5) application that is currently running on a Windows server and I am connecting to SSAS through Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular and the following information:

```
{
    "SSASDataSource": "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false",
    "SSASDataSource_UserName": "windows_username",
    "SSASDataSource_Password": "windows_password",
}
```

You can only connect to SSAS through Windows authentication.

I want to move my app to an ubuntu server.

But I don't know how to connect to SSAS from within ubuntu using Windows authentication

Or is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: Where is SSAS running? Is it on a Windows server on the same network as the Ubuntu server, or in the cloud, etc?

Comment: I have not yet made a final decision on how to implement it, but I do not want to use cloud services @Brenton

Answer (score 2):

This is possible if SSAS is configured for [HTTP access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions).

See the Basic Authentication and Anonymous User section in the documentation for [Authentication methodologies supported by Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/authentication-methodologies-supported-by-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_auth) for more information. If you configure HTTP access, you can then specify the username and password in the connection string with [User ID=...; Password=...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#user-idpassword).